# Is it possible to broadcast a message to all terminals on Linux without subprocess?

Tags: python, linux

One can use `wall` in bash to broadcast a message to all terminals. One can also use `subprocess` in Python to do the same thing, with the same command.

Is there a cleaner way to do this from Python than using `subprocess`? Open some device file and write to it or something? Or does `wall` use some sort of system call to tell the kernel to broadcast a message? What does `wall` do? Can Python do the same thing?

Comment: _Can_ you do the same thing? Universally, yes, especially if you're willing to use `ctypes`. Is it worthwhile? If you care about portability, probably not.

Comment: As a rule, the easiest way to find out what a standard utility does is to read the implementation of one of the minimal/embedded implementations; f/e, the busybox one: https://elixir.bootlin.com/busybox/latest/source/util-linux/wall.c

Comment: You could write into the files in `/dev/pty/`. That will require privileges, though, if they are terminals from other users. `man pty`